# Join in Unix repeat lines claims unsorted

Tags: bash, unix, join

2 csv files are sorted by the key. File 1 contains 2 columns, key in Column 2. File 2 contains multiple columns (I am including just columns 1 and 2 here) and File2:Column 1 repeats the key more than File 1 does in Column 2. I want to join them so every line from File 1 is repeated in File 2 no matter how many times the key is repeated. Join claims that it is not sorted- I checked, the files are sorted, just the repeating elements obviously are bigger in one file than the other. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

File 1

```
Col1-Transcript Col2-GeneName
Transcript1 AATK
Transcript2 AATK
```

File 2

```
Col1-GeneName Col2-SecondaryInfo
AATK   A
AATK   B
AATK   C
AATK   D
```

Hopeful output after Join (or something else?)

```
Col1-GeneName Col2-GeneName Col3-Transcript Col4-SecondaryInfo
AATK   AATK   Transcript1   A
AATK   AATK   Transcript2   A
AATK   AATK   Transcript1   B
AATK   AATK   Transcript2   B
AATK   AATK   Transcript1   C
AATK   AATK   Transcript2   C
AATK   AATK   Transcript1   D
AATK   AATK   Transcript2   D
```

Code used:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 -t , File1.csv File2.csv > Result1.csv
```

Error: File1.csv is not sorted File2.csv is not sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the header "Col1-GeneName" > "AATK" lexically.

use the `--header` option. Also, your data is not comma-separated:

```
$ join --header -1 2 -2 1  File1.csv File2.csv
Col2-GeneName Col1-Transcript Col2-SecondaryInfo
AATK Transcript1 A
AATK Transcript1 B
AATK Transcript1 C
AATK Transcript1 D
AATK Transcript2 A
AATK Transcript2 B
AATK Transcript2 C
AATK Transcript2 D
```

If it's your **data** that's actually unsorted, sort it first. Assuming your shell is bash:

```
# function that reads stdin, prints the first line, then sorts the rest
sort_with_header() {
    IFS= read -r header
    echo "$header"
    sort
}

join --header -1 2 -2 1  <(sort_with_header <File1.csv) <(sort_with_header <File2.csv)
```

Comment: Thanks! Totally was the header! Appreciate it!